# sql: including data from multiple columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have a table that looks like this:

[alt text http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/3929/33732138.png](http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/3929/33732138.png)

another words i would like to take data from columns stuff1, stuff2, and stuff3, and put them together

Comment: You've been given instructions on how to use UNION, but one uses UNION ALL and the other doesn't. UNION ALL does not eliminate dupes, whereas UNION does. This can make UNION ALL significantly more efficient. But only you can know which to use, since your sample data doesn't look real, and it's likely possible that with a non-normalized structure with repeating data you could have dupes and so you'd need UNION instead of UNION ALL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
   practice, stuff1 as stuff, count(*)
from table
group by practice, stuff1
union
select 
   practice, stuff2 as stuff, count(*)
from table
group by practice, stuff2
union
select 
   practice, stuff3 as stuff, count(*)
from table
group by practice, stuff3
```

Answer (score 2):

The [UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) command should suffice for what you want to do:

```
SELECT practice, stuff1 FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT practice, stuff2 FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT practice, stuff3 FROM table
ORDER BY practice
```